# What's the meaning of "steal" in There Is A Pleasure In The Pathless Woods?

Tags: literature, poetry

> There is a pleasure in the pathless woods,
> There is a rapture on the lonely shore,
> There is society, where none intrudes,
> By the deep sea, and music in its roar:
> I love not man the less, but Nature more,
> From these our interviews, in which I steal
> From all I may be, or have been before,
> To mingle with the Universe, and feel
> What I can never express, yet cannot all conceal.

I don't understand the line "From these our interviews, in which I steal."

Comment: Seems to mean *gather*.

Comment: It seems to me to mean _steal away_ (using _steal_ in the sense _go stealthily_).

Comment: ... yes, almost guiltily withdraw from the business of normal life.

Comment: Once you have looked at a good dictionary for the range of meanings the word 'steal', the interpretation is a matter of literary interpretation rather than on English Language Usage or semantics.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You have a dictionary definition, in the SOED, for instance (**9.** Depart or withdraw secretly or surreptitiously; go or come secretely or stealthily; […]
); Your comment is an answer.

Comment: @LPH But (1) Kate suggested this first, in a 'comment' (and I approve); (2) Tuffy points out that required basic research is missing, and (3) Tuffy again points out that this is still literary interpretation (poets sometimes use non-standard definitions). So I'll CV on ... er ... POB grounds.

Comment: From which I **take** all I can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To steal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steal) can mean

> to do something quickly or without being noticed:

Particularly the later in this case.  He slips away from "From all I may be, or have been before,"